# Best practice for documenting actionListeners

Tags: java, coding-style, awt, action, actionlistener

I'm writing a program with a gui that contains a multitude of buttons, text areas and text fields, all with one or more actionListeners, I have about 50 in total.

Are javaDoc level comments required on each or is there a different standard for actionListener methods?

Thanks

Comment: Are any other people likely to use your class?

Comment: Clean self-documenting code is better than excessive comments that try to explain the mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is unlikely that others will use your class, you and only you are seeing the javadocs. In this case, it's important to step back and think about the following:

- Can I understand what everything means?
- If I were to come back in 5 years could I understand what everything means?

If you're working on your own, you don't necessarily need to include javadocs, but at least terse, informative comments such as `//progress bar for download` that tell you what is what. You don't need to restate your set of methods and operations for everything, just make sure you can read it yourself if the time comes that you forget how something works.